# как в List<Integer> добавить объект типа String?

Tags: java, list, коллекции, arraylist

Как в `List<Integer>` добавить объект типа `String`?

Возможно, странный вопрос (мне таким кажется). Задали на обучении, предварительно рассказав что в `List<Integer>` можно добавить только `Integer`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тут можно воспользоваться тем, что дженерики в Java появились не сразу и изначально интерфейс лист был без дженерика. И во имя обратной совместимости он доступен. Таким образом вы можете объявить список чисел, потом его записать в переменную с нетипизированным списком (или имеющуюся переменную скастовать). И в уже нетипизированный список компилятор позволит добавить что угодно.

Вот пример компилируемого и работающего кода:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
      List listO = list;
      listO.add("test");

      //или просто кастуем к нетипизированному списку
      //((List) list).add("test");

      System.out.println("list = " + list);
    }
}
```

Выведет:

> list = [test]

Comment: Позволит, но выдаст предупреждение об использовании сырого типа

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!

Comment: @NowhereMan, смотря где код писать) Я на каком-то случайном сайте набирал - там никаких предупреждений не было) В IDE, понятно, будут. Некоторые линтеры, наверное, даже не дадут такое собрать. Но сам язык позволяет